# Compilation issue ["Root activity type is invalid"] only when compiling from network drive

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, workflow-foundation

When i am compiling .net 3.5 project from network drive
following compilation issue occurs.

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Workflow.Targets(121,5):
>   error : The root activity type is invalid.  Workflow markup
>   validations completed with 1 errors and 0 warnings.

But if i copy the solution in local drive and build ,it works fine.

What could be the issue? How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The first test is to re-do the compilation using the full path, instead of the network mapping drive:

```
M:\yourDynamicView\YourVob\...
# instead of
V:\YourVob\...
```

That will reference the very same view.

Comment: I tried it but still it fails with the same compilation error.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu are you sure your snapshot view has the *same* content as the dynamic one? No version number mismatch in the xoml file and the activities dll? See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/windowsworkflowfoundation/thread/26f2d3d4-fb7f-4924-8543-fe9200806bc5 ? Any issue as in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsworkflowfoundation/thread/1627bc87-5851-4897-9e0d-b18ac1794acc/ and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomlake/archive/2007/12/10/are-you-getting-a-the-root-activity-type-is-invalid-error-with-the-custom-activity-designer-sample.aspx ?

Comment: Yes there is no change between snapshot view content and dynamic view. even we tried creating new snapshot view and new dynamic view. but still the same issue continues

Comment: @Samselvaprabu generally this issue is linked to the fact a dynamic view allow you to access *any* directory (selected by the config spec), as opposed to the snapshot view (and it load rules). Could you make sure the dynamic view only display/select the same set of files than your snapshot view, adding selection rules like "`element /vob/aDir/... -none`" (doesn't select `aDir` and all of its children)

Comment: I should have mentioned that it is UCM. I am loading everything in dynamic view. I have not written any config spec for that

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: no matter, you can still edit the config spec ( `cleartool edcs`) and add rules at the beginning of the config spec.